# PyCharm code completion doesn't work for installed libraries

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I  am using PyCharm community edition 2018.2.

Code completion works fine but just for installed modules if I install external library code completion doesn't work for them. However I have no problem with running code based on them.

I checked that my PyCharm is not in the 'PowerSafeMode'.
I have created project both for main and local Python interpreter.
In the IDE I also try to select installed libraries as a source.
I tried this for PIL library and OpenCV library.

Anyone has and idea what I might be missing or doing wrong?

Comment: However I am starting to think something else might be wrong but I am not sure. I have installed atom IDE and I have the same issues. Even I have installed auto-complete plugin and I wrote path to external libraries in the config section still I have the same results as in PyCharm. Auto-completion shows exactly the same result in both cases.I am running both IDE's on Windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you installed opencv via terminal?
For example, like this.

```
$ pip install opencv-python
$ pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

When I installed opencv through terminal, experienced the same problem.

If so, please try this.
1.Create new Pycharm Project, with new environment using Virtualenv.
2.Install opencv through Pycharm.
 `File` -> `Settings...` -> `Project interpreter` -> `+`

Comment: Yes i thought that might be the case. That why as I said I set up project via local Python interpreter (Virtualenv). When I create project with new environment and install just to it libraries - still no result. I even have tried to mark them as sources and still no result. I also try to reinstall PyCharm also did nothing.